# Why using self.view.layoutIfNeeded() in Animation cause App Freezing?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, layout

In my App, and once the user enters to it, I have too many animations on the dashboard the occurs once only -i.e when the user enter the app for the first time -

I perform the animation like this way in **viewDidAppear** in call `upperViewAnimation()` function which calls another animation functions, to be more clear this is the used code:

```
 func upperViewAnimation() {

    contianerTop.constant = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.45, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion:{(finished)  in

            if finished {
                if noInternetConnection && !noInternetConnectionPopup {
                    self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 50
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    })

                    noInternetConnectionPopup = true
                    openNoInternetConnection()
                }
                else if noInternetConnection {
                    self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 50
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    })

                }
                else {
                    self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 0
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        }, completion: { (finished) in
                           self.pullToRefreshAction()
                    })
                }
                self.notificationButtonAnimationAndMenuButton()
                self.moreAppsLabel.hidden = false
            }
    })
}

func pullToRefreshAction() {
    pullToRefreshContainsFailure = false
    addBlurToCellDelegate?.removeBlurFromAllCells()

    if firstAppear || userLoggedIn {
        self.firstAppear = false
        userLoggedIn = false
        loadingView2.removeFromSuperview()
        sucessView.removeFromSuperview()
        var viewHeight:CGFloat = 50
        if isiPadFlag {
            viewHeight = 60
        }
        loadingView2 = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("GettingDataView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! GettingDataView
        loadingView2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: viewHeight)
        self.noConnectionView.addSubview(loadingView2)
        loadingView2.initView()
        gettingDataForFirstTime = true

        if showPullToRefreshBool {
                self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 50
            }
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
        else {
            self.noConnectionViewHeight.constant = 0
        }
    }  if !gettingData  {
          // I called  requests to get data

        }
}
```

when I perform the previous code my app sometimes freeze, and it seems that the layout NEVER changed (i.e it seems that the app never render the UI )

I wonder if use too many self.view.layoutIfNeeded() cause this problem?

Really I give up on this strange problem,

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: Need to see your viewDidLayoutSubviews.  99% chance you are doing something in there that triggers layout again so it runs in an infinite loop.  Its easy to check; put a print statement in there and see if it prints more than once.

Comment: @JoshHomann hey josh, thanks for your help, actullay I didn't do any important things in viewDidLayoutSubviews, this is my code in it:        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        infoButtoniPad.highlighted = MainDashboardState.InfoStatus
        settingsButtoniPad.highlighted = MainDashboardState.SettingStatus
        profileButtoniPad.highlighted = MainDashboardState.ProfileStatus
        dashboardButtoniPad.highlighted = MainDashboardState.DashboardStatus
        openGreenPointFromDashboard = false
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a completion block for the UIView animations within your first completionblock in upperViewAnimation, and continue running your stuff in the completionblock instead of outside of it.

If that doesn't help. Try to add your methods in viewDidLayoutSubviews . **Also make sure that your animations only get called once at a time**, the viewDidAppear / viewDidLayoutSubviews can get called multiple times, and if called multiple times while your animation is in progress, things might freeze or get wierd.

You can solve this with a simple BOOL flag check when the animation runs, and set it to false when the animation is completed in the finished block.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I didn't get this point: "Try to set a completion block for the UIView animations within your first completionblock in upperViewAnimation, and continue running your stuff in the completionblock instead of outside of it."
can you please explain more, or give me an example on my code please?

Comment: self.notificationButtonAnimationAndMenuButton() self.moreAppsLabel.hidden = false , methods for example, put them in a completionBlock of the animation. But I think your main problem is what I outlined in my answer, viewDidAppear and viewDidLayoutSubviews are not guaranted to only get called once, you need to check with a flag that your animations only run ONCE at a time, that will solve your problems I am sure.

Comment: Thanks, for the mentioned problem, yeah I'm handling it already in a Bool flag :(

Comment: @Rawan So, you added a method to check so that the animations don't run 2 times over eachother and you are 100% sure about this doing tests/logging?

Comment: YUP :'( that's soooooo confused !!

Comment: @Rawan I noticed you are setting contianerTop.constant = 0 , is this a constraint to a containerView within the UIView? If it is, you should try run the containerView.layoutIfNeeded  not self.view.layoutIfNeeded , try this?

Comment: it's a constraint for scroll view and inside the scroll view  I have a container

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where calling `layoutIfNeeded()` inside a UIPropertyAnimator caused a freeze where it appeared that the app got stuck at the `layoutIfNeeded()` call. Wrapping the calls to my animations in `DispatchQueue.main.async` solved my issue ultimately. I'm not entirely sure what was going on, but I was using a call to a delegate method to trigger the animations and maybe the animation was getting started in a non-main thread as a result which was causing strange behavior. Either way, for other people (like me) who landed here googling, try sticking your animations in the main.async queue.

Answer (score 0):

I had an unsatisfiable constraint that autolayout could not break on ios13.
Good luck finding yours if you ever hit this cause I have no pointers.
It was pure luck in my case.